# How to remove columns with duplicate values in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
Years A  B  C  D
2015  1  7  1  13
2016  2  8  2  14
2017  3  9  3  15
2018  4  10 4  16
2019  5  11 5  17
2020  6  12 6  18
```

I want the result to looks as below (the columns with duplicate values removed):

```
Years A  B  D
2015  1  7  13
2016  2  8  14
2017  3  9  15
2018  4  10 16
2019  5  11 17
2020  6  12 18
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or we can transpose the dataset and apply the `duplicated`

```
df1[!duplicated(t(df1))]
#  Years A  B  D
#1  2015 1  7 13
#2  2016 2  8 14
#3  2017 3  9 15
#4  2018 4 10 16
#5  2019 5 11 17
#6  2020 6 12 18
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Years = 2015:2020, A = 1:6, B = 7:12, C = 1:6, 
    D = 13:18), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine the functions `unclass` and `duplicated` to find matching columns and then take the others:

```r
df[!duplicated(unclass(df))]
```

output:

```
  Years     A     B     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2015     1     7    13
2  2016     2     8    14
3  2017     3     9    15
4  2018     4    10    16
5  2019     5    11    17
6  2020     6    12    18
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something fast, try this approach

```
df[!duplicated(as.list(df))]
#   Years A  B  D
# 1  2015 1  7 13
# 2  2016 2  8 14
# 3  2017 3  9 15
# 4  2018 4 10 16
# 5  2019 5 11 17
# 6  2020 6 12 18
```